# mysqldump still fails even with mysqldump --column-statistics=0

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

mysqldump still fails even when using mysqldump --column-statistics=0

```
# mysqldump --column-statistics=0
```

Just returns

```
# mysqldump: [ERROR] unknown variable 'column-statistics=0'
```

Am I missing something obvious here?

EDIT: Even trying to get the version gives me an error.

```
mysqldump -v
mysqldump: [ERROR] unknown variable 'column-statistics=0'
```

Mysql version is:

```
# mysql -v
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 1221
Server version: 5.7.27-0ubuntu0.16.04.1-log (Ubuntu)
```

Which mysql:

```
# which mysql
/usr/bin/mysql
```

It's an Ubuntu server running ServerPilot. The ultimate aim is to run the SiteGround WordPress migration plugin, but it's failing with the Column Statistics error in it's log.

Also tried from the comments:

```
root@vultr:~# mysqldump --no-column-statistics
mysqldump: [ERROR] unknown variable 'column-statistics=0'
root@vultr:~# mysqldump --skip-column-statistics
mysqldump: [ERROR] unknown variable 'column-statistics=0'
root@vultr:~#
```

and then even mysqldump on it's own errors:

```
# mysqldump
mysqldump: [ERROR] unknown variable 'column-statistics=0'
```

Comment: What version of mysqldump utility are you using? Versions prior to 8.0.2  doesn’t support the –column-statistics parameter.

Comment: Try `--no-column-statistics` or `--skip-column-statistics`

Comment: Hi, even if I try to get the version, I get the error: 

mysqldump -v
mysqldump: [ERROR] unknown variable 'column-statistics=0'
root@vultr:~#

Answer (score 2):

If you are running a version of mysqldump that does not support the `column-statistics` argument, you need to *remove* the argument from the command line and config files.

I am running MariaDB `10.0.38-0ubuntu0.16.04.1` which [does not support column-statistics](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-16555), which were added to MySQL 8.0. I ran `strace mysqldump` to find which config files it accessed which were:

```
/etc/my.cnf (did not exist)
/etc/mysql/my.cnf (removed arg)
/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf
/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqldump.cnf (removed arg)
/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-client.cnf
/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-mysql-clients.cnf (removed arg)
/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-mysqld_safe.cnf
/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf (removed arg)
~/.my.cnf (did not exist)
```

Any of those config files that had a section like

```
[mysqldump]
column-statistics=0
```

I removed the `column-statistics=0` argument. This allowed mysqldump to work again.

Answer (score 2):

As of 2023 I had to make `mysqldump` work regardless of version both on **Linux** and **MacOS**. This little script worked to solve the problem. It just checks if argument `--column-statistics=0` fails or not and then adjusts command line.

**Bash, Zsh**

```bash
if mysqldump --column-statistics=0 --version &>/dev/null; then
    colstatVar="--column-statistics=0"
else
    colstatVar=""
fi

mysqldump $colstatVar -rest of arguments
```

**Python**

```python
import os

if os.system("mysqldump --column-statistics=0 --version &>/dev/null") == 0:
    colstatVar = " --column-statistics=0"
else:
    colstatVar = ""

os.system("mysqldump" + colstatVar + " -rest of arguments")
```

Answer (score 0):

And what would be the use of this parameter?:

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin>mysqldump --column-statistics=0 sakila -u root -p >d:\temp\stats.sql
Enter password: ********

C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin>mysqldump  sakila -u root -p >d:\temp\no-stats.sql
Enter password: ********

C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin>d:

D:\TEMP>dir *stats.sql
 Volume in drive D is HDD
 Volume Serial Number is D46B-804B

 Directory of D:\TEMP

17-11-2019  15:41         3.387.169 no-stats.sql
17-11-2019  15:41         3.387.169 stats.sql
               2 File(s)      6.774.338 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  62.853.836.800 bytes free

D:\TEMP>fc stats.sql no-stats.sql
Comparing files stats.sql and NO-STATS.SQL
***** stats.sql

-- Dump completed on 2019-11-17 15:41:41
***** NO-STATS.SQL

-- Dump completed on 2019-11-17 15:41:58
*****


D:\TEMP>
```

Comment: I'm on a Linux server. It's to avoid the error you get when using newer versions of mysqldump: # mysqldump: [ERROR] unknown variable 'column-statistics=0'

Answer (score 0):

https://serverfault.com/questions/912162/mysqldump-throws-unknown-table-column-statistics-in-information-schema-1109 ...

Just download the MySQL 5.7 ZIP Archive from here: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/ and unzip it, then use the mysqldump  file from there.

If you are using MySQL Workbench, you will need to set a path to the mysqldump Tool you downloaded by going to Edit -> Preferences -> Administration (from left hand pane).